# creating pie navigation in html similar to the pie navigation on paranoid android

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wanted to create a pie navigation in my website which looks like the pie navigation in paranoid android [image: pie navigation on paranoid android]

on clicking the navigation button the pie will expand with first set of menus fading the background (like lightbox) on selecting any menu from first level  , the other sub menus will come on top of it
the closest one i saw is [this](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CircularNavigation/index.html#)

Is there some similar one with html css and js? i couldn't find any

Comment: you are asking for the readymade code?

Comment: if there is any readymade code or example which is close to this, i could  edit and finish quickly :)

Answer (score 4):

you can use these **tuts** as a starting point:

http://tikku.com/jquery-radmenu-plugin

http://nikesh.github.io/Pie-Menu/

also this **hovermenu**:

https://github.com/alexcheuk/hovermenu

DEMO: http://www.alexcheuk.com/hovermenu

then its a matter of styling to your liking and adding touch event support